# Is it possible to extract ddl of a package without package body

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am using dbms_metadata.get_ddl function. I extract ddl of package and package body seperate and use them separately, so i dont need PACKAGE BODY's ddl when i ask for PACKAGE ddl. However get_ddl('PACKAGE',some_package) returns PACKAGE and PACKAGE BODY's ddls together.
Is there a parameter to set, or anything else to make this possible...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try `dbms_metadata.get_ddl('PACKAGE_SPEC', some_package instead)` (there is similar with `PACKAGE_BODY`)

Comment: some more infos: (1) must have read rights, (2) executable like this in sql with nice line-breaks in most result viewers: `select replace( dbms_metadata.get_ddl('PACKAGE_SPEC', '<mypkgname>', '<myschema>'), CHR(10), CHR(13)) from dual`, (3) more infos for *12c*: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_metada.htm#ARPLS66885 , https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_metada.htm#BGBIEDIA

Answer (score 1):

For a well formated ddl extraction and easy to use you can get ZoraDDL.
This is a little commandlinetool to extract DDL from the Database with many features.
Look at [ZorraDDL Homepage](http://www.ma-za.de/page_zoraddl.html) for more Information.